# Capture web screen with phonegap and display it?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to implement a page flipper into my android/phonegap app. The screen displays a webpage from a js file, so I'd like to be able to capture it when a button in the page corner is clicked and then pass it into my page flipper as a jpeg or bmp to run its animation. Then clear the image from memory.

Any ideas? thanks

Will

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to use CSS 3D transformation for this flip animation, if your target devices support that feature.

There are plenty of examples on the web. Just search on google for "css3 flip animation".